# Zurb class show-for-large-only aligns all text left

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm building a small site which makes use of the show-for-XXXX-only classes.

My text is center aligned however applying the show-for-large-only class (or small/medium) aligns the text left. I cannot seem to override this.

Here's my HTML:

```
        <div class="content">

        <div class="row">

            <div>

                <div class="large-offset-2 large-8 small-offset-2 small-8 columns">
                    <div class="hero-table show-for-large-up">
                        <div class="hero-copy">
                            Here is my text. It keeps aligning left!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.hero-table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 320px;
        }

.hero-copy  {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-family: "adobe-garamond-pro",serif;
            font-size: 22px;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            height: 320px;
            background-color: red;
            }
```

I wonder if the table code I am using to vertically align the content is clashing with the Zurb class.

Answer (score 1):

The show-for-large-up and related classes apply `display: inherit !important;`, which is overriding your `display: table`. As a result, the whole div shrinks down to the minimum width that it can be (just large enough to fit the text), making it left aligned within its container.

The text itself appears to be left-aligned in all scenarios, regardless of the value of display. You will need `text-align: center` to change that (or you could apply a Foundation class like `large-text-left`).

Comment: I've tried applying Foundation class .text-center but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could try adding `text-align: center;` to your CSS instead. And if all else fails, you could do this: `text-align: center !important;`.

Have you looked in the browser console to see if text-align: center is being applied to the element?